# How can I use Cypress to select an <option> in a specific HTML <select> field?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I Want to select Options from the below HTML Code. `timeentry_lov1` is Select Name which is the 2nd element in Page with the same Name. Also I checked that there is no Frame present in Page.
But Is there any Frame Concept like selenium in Cypress? If not then how do I  work with Select attribute?

HTML:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mssUY.png)

The below Select Statement which I have tried:

```
cy.get('timeentry_lov1',{timeout : 60000}).eq(1).select('NB-860').debug();
cy.get('timeentry_lov1').eq(1).select('NB-860-Test Automation');
cy.select('timeentry_lov1',{timeout : 7000}).eq(1).should('have.value','NB-860');
cy.find('timeentry_lov1').get('select').select('NB-860');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all `<select>` elements with a name equal to "`timeentry_lov1`" in the page, use a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) that filters on the `name` attribute, like this:

```js
cy.get('select[name="timeentry_lov1"]')
```

To select only the *second* `<select>` tag, you can use [`:nth-of-type(2)`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/) to select only the second element that is found:

```js
cy.get('select[name="timeentry_lov1"]:nth-of-type(2)')
```

Now, to actually select the element, just use [`cy.select()`](https://on.cypress.io/select) with the `value` of the `<option>` you want to select:

```js
cy.get('select[name="timeentry_lov1"]:nth-of-type(2)')
.select('NB-860')
```

That should accomplish what you're trying to do.

---

Tip: you can use Cypress's [Selector Playground](https://on.cypress.io/selector-playground) to help you find good CSS selectors to use in your tests. Check out the docs for a video on how it works.

Comment: Thanks for providing Selector Playgound Link. Constructed working selector using that page